# Storing retrieved contacts phone in to database as a string

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am fetching the list of contacts from phone. I am trying to store the selected contact to the database since I  want to retrieve the same later. I am trying to store it as a string. I am using spinner to display list of contacts. But the database is storing the contacts as shown below:

android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@1516bf58

But the application while displaying displays the contacts properly as shown below:

9983635353
Keshav

I want to store the similar way as I see. I have written the following code for this, but presently I am not able to achieve that. pleas let me know what changes do I need to make in order to get this working. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

My code to fetch the contact and save them:

```
contacts1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerContacts);

 cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        int[] to = {R.id.textViewNumber, R.id.textViewEmail};


        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.custom_spinner_row, cursor1, from, to, 0);

contacts1.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
contacts1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               contacts = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Log.d("Pana", "The value of the contact field is " +parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The value of Position selected is " +position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
long id = sqliteHelper.insertData( contacts );
```

Below is my insertData method of database:

```
public long insertData( String contacts) {

        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


        contentValues.put(SQLiteHelper.CONTACTS, contacts);




        id = db.insert(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);


        Log.d("PaNa", "The value of Id is " + id);

        db.close();
        return id;
    }
```

Please let me know what changes do I need to make to save the contact data exactly as I see in the Display of application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Will return `Cursor` object for selected row instead of String.

```
Cursor selectedCursor=(Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String strNumber=selectedCursor.getString(0);
String strName=selectedCursor.getString(1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did this, when I check the value of strNumber and strName I do the following values:

The value of strNumber is Shree
The value of strName is null

I am not getting the number. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: @Kesh1234: ok this is just example in my answer. you should use valid column names to retrieve value from cursor

Comment: @prosper K: Ok. Should I have two columns? one for Contact Name and other for Contact number? Can I store both in same column? I am new to android can you please help me learn about this. Please. Thanks.

Comment: @Kesh1234: try it as `String strNumber = selectedCursor.getString(selectedCursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));`

Comment: @propser K: Worked exactly. Thanks a lot. Can you please suggest me about that database thing? Since I want to retrieve that later. Having two columns is it a good practice?? Please help. thanks for solving this.

Comment: @Kesh1234: yes store both values in separate columns